# How to have one header for two columns in a QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, header, qtablewidget

I want to use a QTableWidget with a particular condition :
I would like to create a table with many columns, then one header for 2 columns and one subheader for each column, like this:

[image: What I need]

As far as I could read, Qt doesn't offer this feature yet. I mean natively. Does anyone know how to do it? So far, what I'm trying to do at the moment is to use 2 superimposed QTableWidgets. Like this :

[image: Illustration of the problem]

But I can't manage to hide that white zone under the header of the first table. Even with the number of rows to 0. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Try to use `QHeaderView`

Comment: Can it be used standalone?

Comment: Can you follow this? - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: No. You only changed a question title. Provide a minimal code sample, that may be compiled and reproduces your problem http://sscce.org/

Comment: I understand. It's a small part of a big project and if I had to provide a _compilable_ code, I should give 4 levels of inheritance. Is it necessary? 

In fact, I think the solution I explored (the 2nd screenshot) is wrong, dirty. That why I'm more asking for _from scratch_ ideas than an improvement of this one...

Comment: You don't need anything that you don't need. Code minimization is an art that you should learn. You don't need these 4 levels of inheritance. Think small an minimal. Put everything into `main.cpp` - just one file. If you don't need a class, add its members to the body of `main()`, etc. It *can* be small. You can look e.g. [at the code of my SO answers](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions) for inspiration.

Comment: As I said, before it's a part of a big project. So, the levels of inheritance are used for... Factorising code ;) And I'm not the only one to work on the project. The question actually is "how to get 2 columns under one header".